# Ansible URI not working with until and async

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to do an API call which sometimes timesout the first try but succeeds the second try. So I need the Ansible task to retry a few times until the response status is 200 (OK).

When using the below tasks it works as expected.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ip:
      - 10.0.0.1
      - 10.0.0.2

  tasks:
    - name: "Get host by IP"
      uri:
        url: "http://cpi.com/webacs/api/v4/data/Devices.json?.full=true&ipAddress={{ item }}"
        method: GET
        status_code: 200
      register: apiResult
      loop: "{{ ip }}"
      retries: 1
      delay: 5
      until: apiResult.status == 200
```

However when I want to do this with async due to the high number hosts I need to check it doesn't work as it seems there is no key status. Instead the output is put into a results_file. I have tried several things here like looking up that results_file (which contains the status code in json) but that also does not seem to work.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ip:
      - 10.0.0.1
      - 10.0.0.2

  tasks:
    - name: "Get host by IP"
      uri:
        url: "http://cpi.com/webacs/api/v4/data/Devices.json?.full=true&ipAddress={{ item }}"
        method: GET
        status_code: 200
      register: asyncApiResult
      loop: "{{ ip }}"
      retries: 1
      delay: 5
      async: 40
      poll: 0
      # until: asyncApiResult.status == 200 <- does not seem to exist
      # until: asyncApiResult is succeeded <- not working because timeout is also a success
      until: (lookup('file', asyncApiResult.results_file) | from_json).get('status') == '200'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

first of all the register variable of the task where you kept async and poll doesn't have status. the next task i.e async_status task contains it so you have to use that task to put the condition on status_code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).